# Arithmetic operation on arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

While performing arithmetic operations on arrays, and the output is an integer why does the output display 1.  or 11. instead of 1.0 or 11.0? Is there a way to display the integer with the floating-point value such as instead of 1. or 11. as 1.0 or 11.0?

Comment: Maybe you can `int(...)` the result

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can format floating numbers to a specific decimal places like this:

```py
pi = 3.1415926
formatter = "{0:.2f}"
output = formatter.format(pi)  # 3.14
```

You can read more about this here: https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to float

```python
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for element in my_list:
    print( float(element) )
```

you will get the "1.0" "2.0" and e.t.c

You can do it on any integer